# Notational question regarding repeated composition and multiplication

Tags: notation

Assume $A$ to be an operator, $B$ a scalar function - the details should not matter too much here.
I know that for an element $c$ the repeated application of the operator can be written as
$$
A(A(A(c)))=(A\circ A\circ A)(c)=A^3(c).
$$

I am looking for a notation of the repeated composition
$$
A(A(A(c)\cdot B)\cdot B)\cdot B
$$
where $\cdot$ is multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that there is established notation for this construction. If you need it often in something you are writing, define one for yourself - perhaps one of
$$
F(A,c,B)
$$
or
$$
(A,B)^n(c).
$$
or
$$
A^n(c;B)
$$
depending on how much you want to stress each of $A$, $B$ and $c$.

Comment: Hm I was hoping there would be some established notation that I didn't know about. But yeah, it's always possible to come up with notation..